# Chrome Always Emulate when DevTools is open

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

If I open DevTools, the Emulation screen is always open and even if I close it and refresh the page, it is still emulating mobile device. I tried to turn off Emulation in Overrides, but it always get checked regardless. I have disabled all my plugins and restarted the browser, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it from settings of Developer Window. In settings you can see `Overrides` there you can change a settings of emulation window.

Comment: my problem is not that I can not turn the feature off. My problem is that the Overrides > Emulation feature is always enabled when I open a new page or refresh the current page.